# Woocommerce отображение товаров в виде таблицы

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы товары отображались в виде таблицы.

**Исходный вариант:**
[image: Исходный вариант]

**Желаемый результат:**
[image: Желаемый результат]

Спасибо

---

Вот содержание моего файла **archive-product.php**

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что подправить :)

```css
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a post type archive
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see      https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author   WooThemes
 * @package  WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

get_header( 'shop' ); ?>

 <?php
  /**
   * woocommerce_before_main_content hook.
   *
   * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
   * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
   * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_website_data() - 30
   */
  do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
 ?>

    <header class="woocommerce-products-header">

  <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

   <h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php
   /**
    * woocommerce_archive_description hook.
    *
    * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
    * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
    */
   do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
  ?>

    </header>

  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

   <?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook.
     *
     * @hooked wc_print_notices - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
   ?>

   <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

    <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

     <?php
      /**
       * woocommerce_shop_loop hook.
       *
       * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
       */
      do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );
     ?>

     <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

   <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

   <?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
   ?>

  <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

   <?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_no_products_found hook.
     *
     * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
   ?>

  <?php endif; ?>

 <?php
  /**
   * woocommerce_after_main_content hook.
   *
   * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
   */
  do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
 ?>

 <?php
  /**
   * woocommerce_sidebar hook.
   *
   * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
   */
  do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
 ?>

<?php get_footer( 'shop' ); ?>
```

Comment: Это слишком объемная задача, выходящая за рамки ответов на StackOverflow. Править надо почти все. Если вы не понимаете, как из этих файлов формируется страница сайта, то с этим вопросом вам лучше обратиться к фрилансерам.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо модифицировать верстку. Берите шаблоны `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php` и `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php`, копируйте их в папку woocomerce вашей темы `wp-content/themes/my-theme/woocommerce/` и правьте их в соответствии с заданием.

Answer (score 1):

Или править шаблоны в [дочерней](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B) теме (см ответ **KAGG Design**) или использовать готовые плагины: https://wordpress.org/plugins/gridlist-view-for-woocommerce/ или [любой другой](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=woocommerce%20list) подходящий

Comment: да специфичное у него задание, я такого в плагинах не видел. Но, может, и найдется.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Да их много всяких. Даже для обычных постов есть не мало (сам дивился когда увидел сколько их в репо). Другое дело насколько целесообразно подобное использовать. Хотя в данном случае это ещё не самое страшное  :)